# Bash: formatting string in printf

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here's the script I am executing:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
function myprint() {
  cp=$1
  targetpermission=$2
  t1="RESOURCE"
  t2="Current Permission"
  t3="New Permission"
  printf "%s : %s ===> %s\n",$t1,$t2,$t3
}

myprint
```

Expected output:

```
RESOURCE : Current Permission ===> New Permission
```

Output I am getting:

```
    [abhyas_app01@localhost safeshell]$ ./test1.sh 
Permission,New : Permission ===> 
,RESOURCE,Current[abhyas_app01@localhost safeshell]$
```

Just what's going on? How do I get the expected output?

PS - `echo` is not an option, because eventually I am going to justify the strings using `%-Ns` where N is a calculated based on terminal width.

Comment: use `printf` without commas, i.e., `printf "%s : %s ===> %s\n" $t1 $t2 $t3`

Comment: And quote your strings, since some of them contain spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shell, `printf` is a command and command arguments are separated by spaces, not commas.

Use:

```
printf "%s : %s ===> %s\n" "$t1" "$t2" "$t3"
```

The double quotes are necessary too; otherwise the `Current Permission` and `New Permission` arguments will be split up and you'll get two lines of output from your single `printf` command.

I note that your function takes (at least) two arguments, but you do not show those being printed or otherwise used within the function.  You may need to revisit that part of your logic.

---

With your current logic:

```
t1="RESOURCE"
t2="Current Permission"
t3="New Permission"
printf "%s : %s ===> %s\n",$t1,$t2,$t3
```

you really pass to `printf`:

```
printf "%s : %s ===> %s\n,RESOURCE,Current" "Permission,New" "Permission"
```

Note how the 'format string' argument includes all of `$t1` and part of `$t2`.  You only provide two arguments for the three `%s` formats, so the third one is left empty.  The output is:

```
Permission,New : Permission ===> 
,RESOURCE,Current
```

with a space at the end of the first line and no newline at the end of the second 'line' (hence your prompt appears immediately after `Current`).